# Override App.config in .NET Core 3.1 when using PublishSingleFile

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I've been trying to find a way to use the `PublishSingleFile` publish option with .NET Core 3.1 and still be able to override the `App.config` file. It gets bundled up into the single executable, but it would be very useful to be able to override it to change settings.

My publish command is simple:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

I've look through the docs, and tried having `App.Config` and `Project.config` files along side it to see if they work, but no luck.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?